# Get one element from a variable with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, selector

I'm (was) basically trying to get one specific element from a variable with multiple elements.

Edit with answer, thanks to @pointy :

```
var $item = $('.item');
var $activeItem = $item.filter('.active');

$activeItem.css('borderColor', 'red');
```

The objective was to use the variable `$item`. This code was simplified to fit the question.

There was other answers, like `$('.item.active')`

Comment: If .active is also a class, `$( '.item.active' )`.

Comment: Could you provide the HTML ?

Comment: There's also `.filter()`.

Comment: While I haven't used a lot of JQuery, I believe `$()` accepts an query selector. So you can combine `#`, `.`, `tagName`, and any other type of selector of any number to select a nested element. See Shilly's comment for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the class selector :

```
$('.item.active').css('borderColor', 'red');
```

Or the `filter()` method :

```
$('.item').filter('.active').css('borderColor', 'red');
```

```js
var item = $('.item');
var activeItem = item.filter('.active');

activeItem.css('borderColor', 'red');
```

```css
.item {
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: green;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item active">Has Active Class</div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item active">Has Active Class</div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: `.hasClass()` and `.is()` doesn't work that way. See here (replace filter by what you want) : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PavLwm